# Graphql, issue with quering parent fields when use upperBound

Tags: lightning-web-components, query, graphql

```
API version: 60
```

Current query with **upperBound**:

```
query accounts {
  uiapi {
    query {
      Partner_Invoice__c(first: 200, upperBound: 5000) {
        edges {
          node {
            Id
            Name {
              value
            }
            Merchant_PI__r {
              Name {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute query **without** using **upperBound : 5000**

```
query accounts {
  uiapi {
    query {
      Partner_Invoice__c(first: 200) {
        edges {
          node {
            Id
            Name {
              value
            }
            Merchant_PI__r {
              Name {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All executed as expected. I can't find any information about this, could anyone answer If I did something wrong?

[image]
[image]

Code beautifier credit [here](https://jsonformatter.org/graphql-formatter).

Comment: What is the API version you are using?

Comment: @prem22,  I use API version 60, enpoint '/services/data/v60.0/graphql'